# Rails testing with factories. Transactional uniqueness problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, transactions, shoulda

I keep getting validation errors when running factories due to uniqueness constraints on fields.  I am using shoulda with factory_girl.  I have a both a unit test and a functional test creating 2 products in the database.  I can run 'rake test:units' and 'rake test:functionals' over and over in any order and everything is will be green but when I run 'rake test' which runs the units followed by the functionals I get errors due to uniqueness.

I also tried creating models to break uniqueness in 2 different unit tests and I get the error then as well.

I have been playing with these settings in test_helper.rb but can't get anything to work

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  self.use_instantiated_fixtures  = false
end
```

Does the transactional_fixtures setting take any effect of factories.  Whats the best way to handle cleaning the database between tests?

Answer (score 1):

(sigh..)

So the problem was that I was copying code from the shoulda docs and ended up declaring my test classes like so:

```
class UserTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
```

However for the transactional fixtures setting to have any effect you need to inherit from ActiveSupport::TestCase by declaring your classes

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
```

Hopefully this can help save someone else some time.